# What trigger words will give resources in Studio Hoppe games, and during what times?

Tags: cheats

Games by Studio Hoppe(Planet Capture, Desert Order, Strategy Combat, etc,) will have seasonal trigger words that when put into the chat will give the player resources. What are some of these trigger phrases? What time frame do they work in?

Answer (score 1):

Here are all the ones I know of-

- 'merry christmas' works around Christmas time
- 'happy easter' works around easter
- 'happy thanksgiving' works around thanksgiving
- 'happy halloween' works around halloween, +12 million steel

*pretty sure cheat phrases are not case sensitive*

Also, this year Studio Hoppe added pumpkins during Halloween. If you run over enough pumpkins you will get another 12 million steel and aluminum.

If you know of any more not on this list, please add it to this answer. Please don't put it in the answer unless you can have done it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

- Merry Christmas
- Happy easter
- Happy Thanksgiving
- Happy Halloween
- Happy new year

Comment: Hi ggezkrunker, can you edit in where you got these? All but one are already mentioned in the other answer.